# Django 1.10 csrf

Tags: python, django, csrf

Не получается импортировать 
 `from django.core.context_processors import csrf` в views.py
Вот settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from django.views.decorators import csrf
```

Источник:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#module-django.views.decorators.csrf